# input.innerHTML into angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hey i'm trying to change my calculator to be more angularJS

```
      var input = document.querySelector('.output');
      var inputVal = input.innerHTML;
```

Is there anything i can use to stop using input.innerHTML?

Comment: why you are not using scope and model

Comment: Study some angular tutorials to find out how the framework works

Comment: @Max : Use scope instead. You can refer my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $scope variable and ng-model in view,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {     
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <input type="number" name="input" id="inputval" ng-model="input" class="form-control"/>
     {{input}}                
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculator, Wow. I worked on something like that when I was learning AngularJS. I hope this will help.

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="values.first" ng-change="doCalculations(sign, values.first, values.second)">
  <select ng-model="sign" ng-change="doCalculations(sign, values.first, values.second)">
    <option value="+">+
      <option value="-">-
        <option value="*">*
          <option value="/">/
  </select>
  <input type="number" ng-model="values.second" ng-change="doCalculations(sign, values.first, values.second)"> = {{result}}
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, Calculator) {
  $scope.values = {
    first: 0,
    second: 0
  };
  $scope.sign = '+';
  $scope.result = 0;

  $scope.doCalculations = function(sign, a, b) {
    switch (sign) {
      case '+':
        $scope.result = Calculator.add(a, b);
        break;
      case '-':
        $scope.result = Calculator.subtract(a, b);
        break;
      case '*':
        $scope.result = Calculator.multiply(a, b);
        break;
      case '/':
        $scope.result = Calculator.divide(a, b);
        break;
    }
  };

});

app.service('Calculator', function() {

  this.add = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };

  this.subtract = function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  };

  this.multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  };

  this.divide = function(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  };

});
```

JSFiddle (with Above Code): http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/st4wj4g4/

JSFiddle (with More Complex Calculator) : http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/ndnjxfba/

Comment: thankyou for your help, i'm new to angularJS, I had the ng-model="output" then when i used $scope.output i was having problems using my operators? is there anyway round this?

Comment: @MaxHughes : Your Welcome. Refer my code / fiddle above. I have used ng-model and then refer those variable in scope for getting values and manipulate those.